# Asynchronous code running out of order with Node and Express Server

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I am new to full stack development, and have a simple Express server that takes input from a HTML form, then queries a mysql server using the mysql npm package. The data from the mysql server is then reformatted into objects that I send to the client side to make a chart and table using chart.js. The problem occurs when I call the function to query mysql and to make the objects, the code is running out of order, and the objects end up being blank by the time I send them using .render.

index.js server code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
var mysql      = require('mysql');
const charts = require('chart.js')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))

app.get('/chart', (req,res) => {
    res.render('charttest.ejs')

})
var allData = {}
var tableArr = new Array(0)
async function getTable(tablename,checkedtimes){  //This is the function that connects to mysql 
    var mysql      = require('mysql');            //and creates the objects
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
     user     : 'root',
    password : '####',
    database: '###'
    });
 
    connection.connect();

    const dataList = new Array(checkedtimes.length)
    var count = 0;
    let allTimes =""
    for(i = 0; i < checkedtimes.length; i++){
        allTimes += `\`${checkedtimes[i]}\`,`
    }
    allTimes = allTimes.substring(0,allTimes.length -1)
    connection.query(`SELECT Date,${allTimes} FROM ${tablename}` ,function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        let dataTimes = new Array(0)
        for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            dataTimes.push(results[i].Date)
        }
        let sets = new Array(0)
        for(let i = 0; i < checkedtimes.length; i++){
            let tableData = {}
            let obj = {}
            let dataProfit = new Array(0)
            for(let j = 0; j < results.length; j++){
                dataProfit.push(results[j][checkedtimes[i]])
            }
            obj.data = dataProfit
            sets.push(obj)
            tableData.Time = checkedtimes[i]
            tableData.profit = dataProfit.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
            tableArr.push(tableData)
        }
        allData.datasets = sets
        allData.labels = dataTimes
        console.log("get table:",allData)
        console.log("gettable:",tableArr)
        //allData and tableArr are the final objects to be sent to client side
        
})
}

app.post('/chart', (req,res) => {
    let prem = req.body.prem;
    let maxloss = req.body.loss
    const checkedtimes = req.body.times

    async function asyncTable(tablename,checkedtimes) {
        await getTable(tablename,checkedtimes)
        console.log("INSIDE asyncTable")
        console.log("async table:" ,tableArr)
        console.log("async table:",allData)
        //Sending the objects to a HTML file where the chart and table are displayed
        res.render('linechart.ejs',{allData:allData,tableArr: tableArr}) 
    }

    switch(prem) { //only including one case here just to show the problem
        case '0.75'://
            if(maxloss === "1x"){
                asyncTable("finalprem75loss1x",checkedtimes)
            }
            break;
}

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("LISTENING ON PORT 3000")
})
```

When I run this code, by the time I get to the .render command the two objects are blank. I included console.logs in different areas of the code to show what the values of the objects were to try to understand what was happening, and it gives me this output:

```
LISTENING ON PORT 3000
[
  '09:45:00',
  '10:30:00',
  '11:30:00',
  '12:30:00',
  '13:00:00',
  '14:00:00'
]
INSIDE asyncTable
async table: []
async table: {}
get table: {
  datasets: [
    { data: [Array] },
    { data: [Array] },
    { data: [Array] },
    { data: [Array] },
    { data: [Array] },
    { data: [Array] }
  ],
  labels: [
    //A bunch of data
  ]
}
gettable: [
  { Time: '09:45:00', profit: 148.0900000000002 },
  { Time: '10:30:00', profit: 118.05999999999985 },
  { Time: '11:30:00', profit: 82.70999999999984 },
  { Time: '12:30:00', profit: 171.4700000000004 },
  { Time: '13:00:00', profit: 187.71999999999966 },
  { Time: '14:00:00', profit: 161.81999999999996 }
]
```

This is completely out of order from what I am expecting. It runs the console.log(checkedtimes) first, which is in the getTable function, however it then immediately skips to running the console.log in the asyncTable function, and then switches back to the getTable function again. I am new to asynchronous programming, so I'm not sure if I am using async properly, but my intention is to have the getTable function(which takes a while to run so I assume this is what is messing up the execution order) run completely first before running the next lines in asyncTable and sending the objects to the client side.

The other problem I have is since the execution order is messed up, I am guessing the .render is happening before getTable finishes, so the objects being sent to the client side are just blank objects. This is shown in the console.logs where the objects in the asyncTable function are being printed out as blank even though they should come after the getTable function is called. If you need anymore info or need my ejs files I can provide them also.

Comment: You're mixing `await` and plain callbacks (with `connection.query()`).  Don't do that.  Thus, you have no organized flow control and cannot control sequencing.  Use ONLY promises for asynchronous flow control and replace the asynchronous callbacks with promise versions of that API and then you can control the order of things happening.